# Creating structs in linux kernel space

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel

So I am doing some work on a linux kernel for class and I am trying to implement a function but first I must define a struct in kernel space. I am getting an error but I am not too sure the cause.

I assume it has something to do with the struct I defined at the beginning but I can't seem to find any issues with it.

UPDATE: Ok I have solved one of the problems. So I will be updating my code snippet and marking lines that are specified in the errors. Line 24 is the line right after the end of the struct.

Here is what I am doing:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/klist.h>
#include <linux/errno.h> 
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>


/********************************************
 *This function adds a new item to the queue
 *
 *If not enough memory return -ENOMEM
 *If there is an error accessing the upper space point return -efault
 *If len is negative return -EINVAL
 *Returns 0 on success 
 ******************************/
struct dataNode
{
  const void * data;
  int length;
  struct list_head * mylist;
}

asmlinkage long sys_writeMsgQueue421(const void __user *data, long len)  //**Line 24**//
{
  newNode->data = pdata;

  newNode->length = len;

  //****Need to add to the linked list****//

  printk("This was passed in: %p and %ld \n",data , len);


  return 0;
}


asmlinkage long sys_readMsgQueue421(void)
{

  printk("This is the read function!\n");
  return 0;
}

asmlinkage long sys_emptyMsgQueue421(void)
{
  printk("This is the clear function!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

And I am getting the following errors when I run the make command:

> CC      msgQueue421/msgQueue421.o msgQueue421/msgQueue421.c:24:1:
>   warning: ‘regparm’ attribute only applies to function types
>   [-Wattributes] msgQueue421/msgQueue421.c:24:12: error: expected ‘;’,
>   identifier or ‘(’ before ‘long’ make[1]: ***
>   [msgQueue421/msgQueue421.o] Error 1 make: *** [msgQueue421] Error 2

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If your second malloc fails, you should free the pointer from your first malloc.

Comment: Please add a comment to your code to highlight which lines are line 24 and 73 (the ones you have errors on)

Comment: On the line, "newNode->data = data;" you probably meant to assign pdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be nice to know what the lines 24 + 73 are, but the 'const' thing is probably caused by

```
  newNode->data = data;
```

you want to assign `pdata` here (not the __user pointer).

Blind guess about the first error group: there is a missing #include so that __user is not defined.

And btw:

```
struct list_head * mylist;
```

in your strict is very likely wrong because you can not deref it.  Use plain `struct list_head mylist;` instead of

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having now (since there are others, some of which have already been pointed out) is that you are missing a `;` to close off your `struct` declaration:

```
struct dataNode
{
void *data;
int length;
struct list_head * mylist;
}

asmlinkage long sys_writeMsgQueue421(const void __user *data, long len)
```

The compiler tries to parse this code, thinking that `asmlinkage long ...` and so on are varible names that will be instances of `struct dataNode`. Of course, `asmlinkage` is almost certainly a macro that expands to who knows what and `long` is a reserved word that cannot be the name of a variable.

So you get errors. Lots and lots of errors.

Generally speaking, when you get an error at line `N` and you see nothing wrong with that line, always look at the last few lines of code that came before the error to see if something is missing.